# How to fix drag area of bootstrap model

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I using Bootstrap v3.3.4 version, I want to prevent model move out of window.
I try with below code for fix drag area for dialog but it not working.

```
$("[role=dialog]").draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header",
            containment: "window"
        });
```

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a `draggable()` component. Do you mean jQueryUI insttead?

Comment: I just try with that and bootstrap have draggable.

Comment: Give us your html and error you get

Comment: "Dialog Draggable" - https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: there model is dragging but goes out of window I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent 2-3 days on googling and other source and finally found solution 
for prevent drag area in browser window only. just need to set **containment** property **window**.

Solution is as below:

```
$("[role=dialog]").draggable({
        containment: "window"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't have draggable(), you need to add JqueryUi for that.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Heading</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this model is moving out of window so I just want prevent it.

Comment: update your code in in plnkr, so we could figure out what is the problem.

Comment: then you can implement that one, above plnkr code working fine right.

Comment: Here i Highlight what is problem with you created code. and that I want to prevent.

Comment: Open that in full page you will got to know.